# No values returned in @AuraEnabled method

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am fairly new to lightning and been trying to create a form which has will need dropdown values. But the dropdown is always appearing blank. Can you please help?

Class

```
public with sharing class SearchController {
@AuraEnabled
   public static List<String> getRegion(){
       return [select Region__c from Loc__c];

     }
 }
```

Component snippet

```
<lightning:select name="Region" aura:id="Region">
                     <aura:iteration items="{!v.Region}" var="region">
                         <option value="{!region}">
                         </option>

                     </aura:iteration>
</lightning:select>
```

Controller on doInit

```
var action = component.get("c.getRegion");
                action.setCallback(this, function(a){
                    component.set("v.Region",a.getReturnValue());

                });
    $A.enqueueAction(action)
```

I also tried hardcoding the values in the class, but that didn't work as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Try to put `state` of the response before adding the `getReturnValue` to attribute and debug. 
`action.setCallback(this, function(response){
var state = response.getState();
            console.log("state " + state);
            if(state === "SUCCESS"){
                var res = response.getReturnValue();

            }
            else{
                console.log("Failed with state: " + state);   
            }});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like you were able to save your apex class. SOQL returns the records and not the primitive data types. Thus your apex method needs to create List on its own.

```
public with sharing class SearchController {
@AuraEnabled
   public static List<String> getRegion(){
       List<String> regionList = new List<String>();
       for(Loc__c loc : [select Region__c from Loc__c]){
            regionList.add(loc.Region__c);
       }
        return regionList;
     }
 }
```

Component:

```
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

<lightning:select name="Region" aura:id="Region">
                     <aura:iteration items="{!v.Region}" var="region">
                         <option value="{!region}">{!region}</option>

                     </aura:iteration>
</lightning:select>
```

That been said, also make sure there are records for Object Loc__c

Comment: Since I have a list of dropdown values that I'd need to get, I changed the doInit method doInit: function(component,event,helper){
helper.getLoc(component);}                                                                         Helper :
    
    getLoc : function(component) {
            var action = component.get("c.getLoc");
            var self = this;
            action.setCallback(this,function(a){
                component.set("v.Loc",a.getReturnValue());
                self.getRegions(component);
            });
            
          $A.enqueueAction(action) },

Comment: getRegions : function(component) {
        var action = component.get("c.getRegion");
        action.setCallback(this,function(a){
            component.set("v.Region",a.getReturnValue());
            
        });
        
       $A.enqueueAction(action) ;
        
    }
    
    These work individually when invoked. But isn't working with multiple enqueue. Is this format correct?